# Replace Only Multiples Of three in c#

Tags: c#, string, replace

How can I replace only *multiples of 3* in C#? Say for example I had the string `"000100000"`, and I wanted `"000"` to be replaced with `"+"` but only every *group of three characters*. Additional condition: the groups should be changed *starting from the end*:, e.g. for `"000100000"` it should output `"+100+"`.

Comment: substring is what you are looking for , google it , try something first.

Comment: This is a very simple algorithmic problem. Everybody who wants to be a programmer and knows some c# basics should be able to figure this one out on his own. Do not be afraid of growing your own expertise in solving such simple questions alone.

Comment: Please add some more details regarding your question - Can the input be a string of any characters? In your above example, why wouldn't the algorithm change 000100000 to +1+00? (000)1(000)00 are groups of three. Also, stack overflow is not a site for having people write answers for you. Please show what you have already attempted or any concrete problems you are having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using *regular expressions*, e.g.:

```
string source = "000100000";

// "+100+"
string result = Regex.Replace(
  source, 
  "0{3,}", 
  match => new string('0', match.Length % 3) + new string('+', match.Length / 3));
```

Tests:

```
  001        -> 001
  0001       -> +1 
  000100     -> +100
  0001000    -> +1+
  00010000   -> +10+
  000100000  -> +100+ 
  0001000000 -> +1++
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a regular expression for this.

```
(0{3}(?!0+))
```

This uses a negative lookahead to make sure there aren't any other zeros after a group of three 0s - in other words, for a sequence of an arbitrary number of 0s, it'll only match the last 3.

You can modify this if you want to do something subtly different looking lookaheads and lookbehinds.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Substring:

```
 string strReplace = "000100000";

//Store your string on StringBuilder to edit the string
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 

 sb.Append("+");
 sb.Append(strReplace.Substring(0, 3)); //Use substring, 0 is the start of index and 3 is the length as your requirement 
 sb.Append("+");
 sb.Append(strReplace.Substring(3, 3));
 sb.Append("+");
 sb.Append(strReplace.Substring(6, 3));
 sb.Append("+");

 strReplace = sb.ToString(); //Finally replace your string instance with your result
```

Or by for loop but this time instead of using substring, we use Char array to get every char in your string:

```
        string strReplace = "000100000";
        char[] chReplace = strReplace.ToCharArray();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int x = 0; x <= 8; x++)
        {
            if (x == 0 || x == 3 || x == 6 || x == 9)
            {
                sb.Append("+");
                sb.Append(chReplace[x]);
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append(chReplace[x]);
            }
        }
        sb.Append("+");
        strReplace = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Eh, `(x == 0 || x == 3 || x == 6 || x == 9)` looks *suspecious*, why not `... && x == 12 || x == 15 || ... || x == 3003 || ...`?  You, probably, mean `x % 3 == 0`

Comment: If I will use &&, it will only triggered if all of the condition on x are met.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, a bunch of these answers are addressing detecting groups of 3 `'0'`s. Here's an answer that deals with groups of 3 anythings (reading the string in groups of three characters):

```
string GroupsOfThree(string str)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i + 2 < str.Length; i += 3)
    {
        string sub = str.Substring(i, 3);
        if (sub.All(c => c == sub[0]))
            sb.Append("+");
        else
            sb.Append(sub);
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a replace regular expression.

```
"[0]{3}|[1]{3}"
```

The above Regular Expression can be use like below in C#:

```
string k = "000100000";
Regex pattern = new Regex("[0]{3}|[1]{3}");
pattern.Replace(k, "+");
```

Answer (score -1):

reversing the string before you replace and after solves your problem.

something like:

```
string ReplaceThreeZeros(string text)
{
    var reversed = new string(text.Reverse().ToArray());
    var replaced = reversed.Replace("000","+");
    return new string(replaced.Reverse().ToArray());
}
```

Comment: I don't see how reversing the text helps. Also, the question was not about groups of 3 `'0'`s, but about groups of 3 in general.